# Call to a member function temporaryUrl() on string (livewire upload image)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have struggled, with this problem 3days day. could not figure how to solve it.

here is my livewire model.

```
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class EditProfile extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
    public $avatar;
    public $coverPic;
    
    
    public function mount()
    { 
        $this->avatar = auth()->user()->avatar;
        $this->coverPic= auth()->user()->coverPic;
    }
    protected $rules =[
        'coverPic'=> 'image|mimes:png,jpg,gif,webp,jpeg',
    ];

    public function updatemain()
    {
        $this->user = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);
        if ($this->avatar) {
            $avatar = $this->avatar->store('/usersAvatar' ,'public');
            
        }
        if ($this->coverPic) {
            $coverPic = $this->coverPic->store('/usersCover' ,'public');
        }
        $this->validate();
        $this->user->update([
            'avatar'=> $avatar,
            'coverPic'=> $coverPic,
        ]);
        session()->flash('succes','informatino succesfully updated');  
    }
    

    public function updated($property)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($property);
    }
}
```

and bellow is my view where I've tried to render the images.

```
//right here is to display the coverPic

  <div class="banner_in" style="background-image:url('@if($coverPic) {{$coverPic->temporaryUrl() ? : asset('storage/'.auth()->user()->coverPic)}}@endif">

//here is to display the avatar picture.

  <img src="@if($avatar){{$avatar ? $avatar->temporaryUrl() : asset('storage/'.auth()->user()->avatar)}}@endif" alt="">
  <input type="file"  wire:model.lazy='avatar' id="profile_img">

  <input type="file" id="cover_pic" wire:model.lazy="coverPic"  >
```

because there is image path already saved in the database the the function temporaryUrl is triying to perform the action on that path. which is a string.resulting in the problem above.

I want the already existed image to be displayed. and the uploaded one to be shown only on the update.

Comment: Strings don't have functions associated with them. How is `temporaryUrl` related to the string? Please add more details. Is `$avatar`/ `$coverPic` already the image location and that function is not needed?

Comment: @user3783243 the temporayUrl is a livewire function used to preview the uploaded image. please refer to this article  [link](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads#preview-urls) to understand more.

Comment: It seems that `$avatar` wouldn't change to the uploaded file until the next line. I'm not seeing where `$avatar` can be interpreted as anything else except the database value at that point. In vanilla PHP, I might start debugging by checking if `$avatar` is a string, with `is_string($avatar)`. Pseudo code for this would look like `is_string($avatar) ? display database image : display uploaded image->temporaryUrl()`. This is only how I would start debugging. The code should be optimized past this point.

Answer (score 0):

Because you assign $avatar and $coverPic property in the mount function, the initial value of them will be a value of string type (such as: 'avatar.jpg') if auth()->user() has avatar/coverPic. That's the reason you can't call $avatar->temporaryUrl() or $coverPic->temporaryUrl().

So just try removing the below function from your component

```
public function mount()
{ 
    //or comment out 2 below lines
    //$this->avatar = auth()->user()->avatar;
    //$this->coverPic= auth()->user()->coverPic;
}
```